# error: indexoutofbound. when read some bytes of file

Tags: android, file, byte

I want to read some bytes of a file, from "offset" and it'length is "size". So i use FIleInputStream and this code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[size];
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(inputFile);
System.out.println("offset:"+offset+","+"size:"+size);
fis.read(data, offset, size);
```

So I have true values of offset and size, but I receiver error: indexoutofbound. I don't understand. Can anyone show how I fall and whether have any other right way to do it?

Comment: isn't `fis.read(data, offset, size);` should be `fis.read(data, offset, size-1);`

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) tells you:

```
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
```

```
Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - If off is negative, len is negative, or len is 
    greater than b.length - off
```

be aware that the indexes are 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you've got in `offset` here, but `offset` is meant to be the offset (i.e. starting index) in the array where you want to store the bytes.

So you're trying to read `size` bytes into your array, starting at position `offset` - hence an `IndexOutOfBounds` if `offset > 0`. You need `offset` to be 0, and it should work.

Comment: yes! you are right! :) thanks for your explain. i confuse the offset and size param. i thought offset of file but it is offset of array in real. So have you simple way to read some byte from offset and last size from a file?

Comment: The `read` method will return the number of bytes read - you can use that with successive reads to calculate the file size... or convert the input data into some other form.